# How to block access to sub-domain by IP address

Tags: azure, iis, url-rewriting, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I am using Azure web apps and need to block access to my pre-live environments.

I've attempted using the suggestion made here but it doesn't seem to work: https://learnwithshahriar.wordpress.com/2015/08/06/azure-website-101-restrict-access-on-your-staging-site/

My example:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Block unauthorized IP to dev site" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^dev-slot.example.com" />
        <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="111.222.333.444" negate="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Site is not accessible" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

It basically does nothing and I've tried various minor alterations to no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to simply block the IP address within the web.config? I tested the below out in an Azure Web App and was able to block access.

```xml
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true">    
           <clear/> <!-- removes all upstream restrictions -->
           <add ipAddress="83.116.19.53"/>   <!-- block one IP  -->                
           <add ipAddress="83.116.119.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0"/>   <!--block network 83.116.119.0 to 83.116.119.255-->               
        </ipSecurity>
      </security>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Reference Site: [https://www.stokia.com/support/misc/web-config-ip-address-restriction.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20160409182939/http://www.stokia.com/support/misc/web-config-ip-address-restriction.aspx)

Comment: Only to certain domains. We're using the swap functionality in Azure. This means that when you swap from a staging environment to prod the configuration goes with it.

Therefore we'd have to do some sort of config manipulation, which means bringing a script into our deployment tools, lot of fuss.

Hoping that I can specify my dev domains and restrict access to those.

Comment: I have experienced the same problem you are. Seems like you have to be willing to manually make changes to your server to get things done. The automated process we are using automatically spins up the server and does all the swapping. We've done code side IP white-listing for our non-production environments. It might be another option to bring up a non-prod Web App and do your development there then when you are ready to go to production deploy to the production web app. Not sure how much this helps but from what I can tell the options to do what you are looking for are pretty limited.